# filtering out empty columns from mysql query with php

Tags: php, mysql

this is one of 27 loops i'm using to check if a particular mysql query returns any empty columns and thus filter them out. But it doesnt seem to be working. Any help would be much appreciated.....

```
foreach($array as $row) {
            if(!empty($row['TROVE'])) {
            $trove = print "<th>TROVE</th>";
            break;
        }

}
```

Comment: What about `WHERE TROVE IS NOT NULL` or `WHERE TROVE != ''` in your query to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking that in x number of loops ... it's much efficient to check the condition in your query like ...

```
where TROVE is not null or TROVE <> ''
```

Comment: This cannot be done as its part of a search engine so depending on the search keyword the database will be queried, therefore i would have to dynamically build up very complex queries, which isnt really what i want to do.

Comment: But that's then won't be the best practice and your code will perform slow.

Comment: That I've been thinking while making the code, can you suggest another method to generate table columns...because i can't understand how I can achieve the same with mysql querying